# Blackbox-tests vs. whitebox

Tags: unit-testing

I´ve read [here](http://googletesting.blogspot.ru/2013/08/testing-on-toilet-test-behavior-not.html) that black-box-testing (testing just the API without implementation-details) is prefered in most situations. However if I write only black-box-tests where I do not care for the actual implementation from where do I know how to handle any dependencies of the method to test? Imagine we make a database-call in our method to test. Usually I would fake that call in a way that allways returns some fake data in order to test if my own method handles that data accordingly. Within my test I don´t care from where the data actually comes so I fake it.

On a black-box I do not know what to fake and how to do it, whereas on a white-box I know the internals and therefor which calls to fake.

So my question is: is dependency-handling any relevant to black-box-tests at all?

Comment: Feels like a big endian/little endian argument. It's your class; it's your test.  Inject the mocks and get on with it.

Comment: @duffymo To do so I have to know WHAT to mock and therefor the internals.

Comment: Yes, but it's your class.  You know what the dependencies are.  You're talking about unit testing your stuff, aren't you?  If it's classes written by others, you have the source code.  Don't you?  Or do you close your eyes when you're coding?   By all means close your eyes and pretend you don't have the source code. Write your unit tests by only referring to the javadocs.  How can that work?

Comment: That depends on the original design. If the API assumes explicit dependencies, e.g. with dependency inversion / injection, then you can apply mocks without any implementation details.

Comment: @duffymo I see, that means as long as I have the source-code I should not care about black-boxes, shouldn´t I?

Comment: I'm saying that this is the kind of bike shed argument that wastes time and isn't useful.  Test your classes; make sure they work; get on with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand the intent of the linked article. The suggestion is to focus on the behaviour and not the implementation, as this means that your tests will be less brittle and will not need to change if the implementation changes. Don't confuse internal implementation and dependencies of you class. If you class has dependencies then mocks of these can be provided (unless your tests are integration tests or the dependencies are implementation details). There is a difference between changes to the implementation and changes to the dependencies.

In your example if you are calling the database to get some data and you want to mock this then this is fine and your setup will need to take this into consideration, but focus on the expected inputs and outputs in the test, don't try and check the internals of the class, or interactions with helper classes which are an implementation detail.

In the example linked to the `AdderFactory` change is an implementation detail change and not a dependency change as nothing here needs to mocked and the existing test will continue to test the `AdderFactory` as well.

If you could change the implementation of the class and you don't need to change the test then you are along the right lines, if you need to change every test because you changed the internals of the class (not the dependencies of the class), then this is a smell and you should look again at your tests.

Comment: In the given example we add a dependency that might do much work before resulting the actual result. Thus I´d may mock the factory itself. This is what I consider an implementation-detail.

Comment: the dependency is that your class requires a 'result' from the other class, the implementation detail is that you are doing via the database.